# Insert a variable from JS to Django form input field

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I am writing a form that pays an employee's mileage between two cities.  I am using the Google Maps API to get the information.  I am running a script that yields a variable `drivingDistanceMiles`.  I would like to populate the field in my Django form `mileage`, which saves to a python variable `distance`.

Here is a snippet of my form html:

```
<form action="" method="post"><% csrf_token %}
{{  form.non_field_errors  }}
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{  form.distance.errors  }}
    <label for="id_distance">Mileage claim:</label>
    {{  form.distance  }}
</div>
```

There is a distance calculator on the page just above the entry.

In my forms.py `distance = forms.CharField(max_length=20, required = False)`.  I made this a CharField instead of an IntField in case my employees (not the most computer savvy bunch) add the word 'miles' at the end.

THE QUESTION:  Is it possible to get the value of `drivingDistanceMiles` to auto-populate when the user enters their city info into the distance calculator?

Comment: Here is the HTML for the tag I want to adjust:                  `<div class="fieldWrapper">
<label for="id_distance">Mileage claim:</label>                <input id="id_distance" type="text" name="distance" maxlength="20" />
</div>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using plain javascript (not jQuery or any frameworks) you can access the field by `document.getElementById('id_distance').value`. You can set it's value by `document.getElementById('id_distance').value = <some_var>;`

Comment: At the end of my javascript I added `document.getElementId('id_distance').value = drivingDistanceMiles` and it just reloads the form.  I am using Django frameworks/templating language for the HTML generation.  I have set the distance calculator on the same page but in its own form tag to prevent the Django form from attempting to post on clicking the calculate button.  Therefore the output field (`id_distance`) is in a different form than the distance calculator.  Does this matter?

Comment: How are you calculating the `drivingDistanceMiles`? You could add this line at the end of the calculating function and it should update the `id_distance` field whenever `drivingDistanceMiles` is updated. Adding more HTML could help answering the question. Can you post the whole form (including the part that has the city input)?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/KtHYEYLD  for the raw source (before template tags are rendered via Django)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/YxcJrKF6 for rendered HTML.  To reduce the size of the post I removed some of the other form fields and the head.  Let me know if you need any of that data.

Comment: At the end of the first comment `getElementId` is misspelled, it's `getElementById`. All you should need to do is `document.getElementById('id_distance').value = drivingDistanceMiles` at the end of the `showLocation` function. If you are still having issues you can use [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and copy in the generated html and javascript and I can take a look at it.

Comment: It looks like the typo was the problem.  Thanks!