# Javascript variable not passed to Django form textarea

Tags: javascript, django, django-forms, django-templates

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    function dropfunc(){
        var s = document.getElementsByName('parameters')[0];
        var text = s.options[s.selectedIndex].text;
        document.getElementById("mytext").value = text;
        document.getElementById("distance").value = text;
    }
</script>
    <form action="/summarize_text/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p><b> Text Summarizer</p></b>
    <select name = "parameters">
        <option>Sentence1</option>
        <option>Sentence2</option>
        <option>Sentence3</option>
        <option>Sentence4</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" onclick="dropfunc()" value="Submit">
    <input type="text" id="mytext">
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        <label id="distance">Sentence</label>
        {{form.text_data}}
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In this code the textbox mytext is responsive to changes in the dropdown but the `dropfunc()` should make changes in the django form variable distance as well. Please suggest what I am doing wrong. In **forms.py** I have defined text data as follows:

`text_data = forms.CharField(max_length=20000000, widget=forms.Textarea())`

Comment: a `label` element has no `value` property. and an `option` element has no `text` property ... perhaps you're looking for *`element.textContent`*?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11569967/insert-a-variable-from-js-to-django-form-input-field This link solves a similar query for reference.

Comment: @JaromandaX I want to change the value of text_data in the django form.

Comment: oh - well if that other question doesn't help, then I have no other suggestions

Comment: put {{form.text_data}} in <span class="xyz"> than inside dropfunc()  change text for class xyz

Comment: @GireekBansal Please show us the form definition and view where you are passing any initial data in.

Comment: @Krystofee This is the forms.py: class TextForm(forms.Form): text_data = forms.CharField(max_length=20000000, widget=forms.Textarea(), )